# Can't import ModelConfigurationDetails in the OCI notebooksession using conda env

Tags: python, conda, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-python-sdk

I am using OCI notebook session for model deployment. cloned oci-python-sdk in the env.
env: Python [conda env:generalmachinelearningforgpusv1]

(/home/datascience/conda/generalmachinelearningforgpusv1) bash-4.2$ oci --version
2.16.1

Facing below error:

```
    import oci
    from oci.data_science import DataScienceClient, DataScienceClientCompositeOperations
    from oci.data_science.models import ModelConfigurationDetails
    /home/datascience
    ERROR:ads:ADS Exception
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/datascience/conda/generalmachinelearningforgpusv1/lib/python3.6/site- 
    packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-36-f4bbafdb9ab7>", line 8, in <module>
    from oci.data_science.models import ModelConfigurationDetails
    ImportError: cannot import name 'ModelConfigurationDetails'
    ImportError: cannot import name 'ModelConfigurationDetails
enter code here
```

When I am using **python3** environment it is running fine. I compared modules installed in both the env and installed the left once in conda env. But I need to use **Python [conda env:generalmachinelearningforgpusv1]** env, bcz in python3 env facing issues with other module installation.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to upgrade the OCI Python SDK in the new virtual environment. We recommend using the latest version, since the one you are using is almost a year old.

I see you checked the OCI CLI version here

```
bash-4.2$ oci --version 2.16.1
```

This OCI CLI version uses a version of the OCI Python SDK (specifically, v2.25.1) which does not have the models you are looking for.